# MeasureIt giving error on rendering

Tags: add-on, error

All worked perfectly until I press render on MeasureIt tab. Here's the error

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\blender\Blender\Blender Main Soft\3.6\scripts\addons\measureit\measureit_main.py", line 1729, in execute
    if render_main(self, context) is True:
  File "D:\blender\Blender\Blender Main Soft\3.6\scripts\addons\measureit\measureit_render.py", line 33, in render_main
    settings.color_depth = '8'
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "8" not found in ('16', '32')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the color depth parameter from 8 to 16 in the *render.py* file within the *measurelt* addon folder.

Comment: Best reported as a bug in that case! Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender or via the 'Report a Bug' button under the addon's Preferences > Addons entry.